# Prove that no vertex can be cut vertex of both G and its complement

Tags: graph-theory

"Show that if $v$ is a vertex of a simple connected graph $G$ then $\overline{G} - v = \overline{G-v}$.
Also proof that no vertex can be a cut vertex of both $G$ and $\overline{G}$."

I have proved that the complement of a disconnected simple graphs is connected with the following:

Let $U$ and $W$ be different components of G and let $u,u' \in V(U)$ and $w,w' \in V(W)$. The edges $uw, uw', u'w$ and $u'w'$ are not in $E(G)$, so they are in $E(G')$. Thus there are paths $uwu'$ and $wuw'$ in $\overline{G}$.

I managed to solve the question and posted the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u,w\in V(G)$. The edge $uv$ is in $\overline{G}- v$ iff it is not in $G$ and is not incident to $V$ so $u$ and $w$ are both distinctfrom $v$). This holds iff $u$ and $w$ are vertices of $G-v$ that are not adjacent in $G-v$, so $\overline{G}-v =  \overline{G-v}$.

If $v$ were a cut vertex of both $G$ and $\overline{G}$ then $G-v$ and $\overline{G}-v$ would both have two components. Bit this is impossible, as if one one $G-v$ and $\overline{G-v}$ is disconnected then the other is connected using the results from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Let v be a cut-vertex of G and $v_1, v_2$ be two vertices of $G - v$. If they are located in distinct components of $G - v$, the edge $(v_1, v_2) \notin E(G) \; \implies (v_1, v_2) \in E(\overline{G}) \; \implies (v_1, v_2) \in E(\overline{G} - v)$.
 Otherwise if $v_1, v_2$ belong to the same component of $G - v$, then $\exists w \in V(G)$ that lies in a different component of $G - v$, because v is a cut-vertex. Thus $(v_1, w), (w, v_2) \in E(\overline{G} - v)$. Hence, there is a $v_1, v_2-path$ in $\overline{G} - v$.